# grid-layout of multiple ggplots generated with lapply function over facet_grid()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a function that automatically generates a long list of faceted ggplots using `facet_grid`. I would now like to further 'grid' these faceted plots into 3x5 blocks equivalent to letter-sized pages so they can serve as physical reference material. Is it possible to generate such layouts within ggplot?

[I hope that it is not necessary to provide a repex for this problem. I believe the question is pretty clear and I'm not looking for a direct solution--simply being pointed in the right direction or steered clear of a pointless rabbit hole would be useful.]

Comment: Check out the [patchwork](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/) package - it's very user-friendly and should have exactly the functionality you need.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Yet more to learn but looks very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you again @A.S.K. The patchwork package is just what I needed.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(patchwork)

# using lapply with ggplot

df <- data.frame(x=c("a", "b", "c"), col1=c(1, 2, 3), col2=c(3, 2, 1), col3=c(4, 2, 3))
cols <- colnames(df[2:4])
myplots <- vector('list', 3)

plot_function <- function(y_column, data) { 
     ggplot(data, aes_string(x="x", y=y_column, fill = "x")) +
     geom_col() + 
     labs(title=paste("lapply:", y_column))
}


myplots <- lapply(cols, plot_function, df)

# using patchwork for layout

patch1 <- myplots[[1]] + myplots[[2]] / myplots[[3]] + plot_layout(guides = 'collect')
patch2 <- myplots[[1]] / ( myplots[[3]] | myplots[[2]] ) + theme_grey() + plot_layout(guides = 'collect')
patch1 / patch2
```

[image: quick try with patchwork]

Now I just need to sort out how to generate the layout programmatically from a list and understand the layout options so the plots nicely fill up a letter-sized page. But this was way easier than I had hoped.